# is SSL/TLS certificate vulnerable

Tags: tls, network, openssl

To my understanding, the client verifies the server certificate by checking whether the issuer DN (Distinguished Name) is equal to the subject DN in the root certificate ? If this is the case, anyone can put a Microsoft's DN in his certificate's issuer DN and send it to the client along with a Microsoft's certificate that is being trusted by every computer. How does this certificate validate and verifies the server then ?

Comment: You are mistaken.  The client checks the signature of the certificate to determine if it is legitimate.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

No, not everyone can send a modified certificate to the client. Every certificate is digitally signed and the clients check these signatures.

So you either need to ...

- create a fake signature (which is cryptographically hard),
- get a certificate autority to sign your certificate (which they should refuse to, because you are not owner of microsoft.com)
- or sign the certificate with a self-made root certificate (then you can sign anything - but no PC will trust you as long as your root certificate is not imported into their system).

Comment: the certificate's signature is actually, a hash of the certificate encrypted by CA's private key ?

Comment: so calculate the hash of the server certificate, then, In server certificate I decrypt the signature Value with CA's public key, and compare both hashes. Am i right now ?

Comment: @MamoonAhmed I think you got it right.

Comment: oh . . .  you dont know how much those words gave me pleasure ..... should i delete the question or leave it ?